# Java Spring automatically finds and parses xml file with bean declarations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I was lately playing with one sophisticated Spring MVC application. I set my servlet dispatcher to look automatically for Controller classes.

```
<!-- Scans for application @Components to deploy -->
<context:component-scan base-package="com.example."/>
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:spring-configured />
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/>
```

So as I understand it runs through all jars and tries to find all controllers.

Interestingly, in one of the jars on the classpath I have the following file myFile.xml with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

<!-- This bean is the parent ApplicationContext for the WebApplicationContexts defined in the WARs. 
     The context files listed here should contain beans that are used by all WARs, for example Services and DAOs. -->
<bean id="grants-app.context" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
            <value>/example/config.xml</value>
            <value>/example/app-config.xml</value>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
</beans>
```

Somehow Spring picks up this file and tries to make the bean defined in this file. I don't understand this behavior  - I only told Spring to look for Controller classes. Can please somebody explain me what is going on here?

Comment: Is it loading beans from config.xml and app-config.xml file ?

Comment: Yes the Spring proceeds and tries to load those beans.

Comment: I think this is not at all possible.

Comment: I have edited this question to show all settings for servlet dispatcher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to see your web.xml.
When each of your web app wants to access common source code like service and daos(which could be in a jar in EAR as in your case), you specify it in context parameters like sample below:

```
    <!--  root application context -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:rootContextBeans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <!--  shared service layer - parent application context -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>locatorFactorySelector</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:myFile.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>parentContextKey</param-name>
        <param-value>servicelayer-context</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```

and myFile.xml will be like

```
    <beans>
      <bean id="servicelayer-context" class="org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext">
        <constructor-arg>
          <list>
                <value>/example/config.xml</value>
                <value>/example/app-config.xml</value>
            </list>
        </constructor-arg>
      </bean>
    </beans>
```

It is this ContextLoaderListener/contextLoader(older spring version) in web.xml which loads these files from myFile.xml